# Backup solution for a filesystem containing hard links

Tags: linux, backup

I have a Linux filesystem that I would like to make backups of. I want to image the entire filesystem, for later restoration if needed. However, this particular filesystem contains multiple hard links to some files, which must be preserved by the backup and properly re-linked when it is restored, exactly as they are now.

Is there a Linux tool that can efficiently image a filesystem, preserving hard links in the process? I would prefer an open source one if possible, although I'm willing to consider all options.

Comment: I don't understand why would you lose hard links while doing a filesystem image...

Comment: Well, my assumption was that some/many ways of doing it would create multiple copies of a hard-linked file, rather than making multiple hard links that point to the same file. Am I incorrect about that?

Comment: Yes, you're incorrect about that. An image is an exact copy on a bit basis. You're talking about copying not imaging.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I guess I just want a standard imaging tool then. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make an image of the filesystem, you will get it exactly as it was in the moment you did the image (links and everything, these are part of the filesystem information). You're probably mistaken the filesystem itself with the logical entities it represents (files, directories...).

I personally used standard tool `dd` long time ago to make/restore partition backups, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Note that you can't make a filesystem image (safely) with a copy like that if it's mounted read-write.

Answer (score 2):

Rsync with the -H (--hard-links) option will do what you want, preserving linked files as the same inode in the target filesystem.  Obviously it only works if the target filesystem supports hard links.